# what all things are necessary to run the emulator script for an Android kenel image

Tags: android, kernel

I have compiled a goldfish kernel under panda platform and created a `zImage` in the path `panda/goldfish/arch/arm/zImage`.

Now I'm using this command to run the emulator:

```
./emulator -kernel /home/kpit/android_sd/panda/goldfish/arch/arm/boot/zImage -avd avd
```

which is giving me the error:

```
PANIC: Could not open: /home/kpit/android-sdk-linux//.android/avd/avd.ini
```

Can anybody tell me what is the problem?

I am new to android. So please consider this while answering, so that I can understand what is the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you have requested the Android Virtual Device (AVD) named 'avd'  (per your options '-avd avd' but there is no such device. What is in your avd dir (try 'ls /home/kpit/android-sdk-linux/.android/avd)?